# Disable Keyboard Popup for Bootstrap datepicker on Mobile (Rails 4, Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have  Rails 4 app which utilizes the Bootstrap datetimepicker plugin.

My form field looks as follows:

```
<%= f.text_field :event_date, id: "event-datepicker", class: "form-control" %>
```

The Jquery Associated with it is as follows:

```
$('#event-datepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'LL'});
```

A calendar pops up when I click on the text-field and the selection on the calendar is input into the text-field. **Now the problem is, on the mobile, when I select the text-field, the mobile keyboard appears over the calendar that appears.** How do I disable the mobile keyboard so I only select a date from the bootstrap calendar? I tried searching for answers but nooone had the exact scenario I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it readonly:

```
<%= f.text_field :event_date, id: "event-datepicker", class: "form-control", readonly: "true" %>
```

... and add some css to prevent the gray background:

```
#event-datepicker {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ".attr('readonly','readonly')" and you're all set.

```
$('#event-datepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'LL'}).attr('readonly','readonly');
```